# JSF f:ajax does not render immediately

Tags: jsf, ajax-update

I have a input text like this:

```xml
<h:inputText value="#{someValue}">
   <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{someMethod}" render="someDataTable"/>
</h:inputText>
```

I have a data table like this:

```xml
<h:dataTable value="#{someList}" var="anyVar" id="someDataTable">
    some things
</h:dataTable>
```

When I change the text in the input text, the change is not hapenning immediately, rather I have to click on the page on anything to get the required result in the data table.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On HTML input text elements, the HTML DOM `change` event is only fired when the element's value has been changed **and** the element loses focus (i.e. the `blur` event has been fired as well). Clicking anywhere else on the page or tabbing to next element would fire the `blur` event. So the described symptoms perfectly matches the specified behaviour.

You're most probably interested in the `keyup` event.

```xml
<f:ajax event="keyup" ... />
```

Keep in mind that this fires the Ajax request on every keystroke which is not necessarily cheap. You might want to add a delay of ~200ms.

```xml
<f:ajax event="keyup" delay="200" ... />
```

#### See also:

- [What values can I pass to the event attribute of the f:ajax tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886453/what-values-can-i-pass-to-the-event-attribute-of-the-fajax-tag)

Comment: thank you so much!! the keyup thing did the job. also its fine if it returns result for every keystroke.

Comment: also on this note, where can i find the full list of events?

Comment: The average HTML DOM tutorial/reference should have such an overview. [Here's an example](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp) (just think the "on" prefix away). You can find another overview and excellent compatibility tables [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/index.html).