# What values can I pass to the event attribute of the f:ajax tag?

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2

I am trying to find a list of all the possible values I can pass to the attribute `event` of the `f:ajax` tag.

I know that I can also pass function names from my .js files, but what I need just the ones that come with JSF.

I only know about click mouseover and keyup, but I am sure there are more. Just don't know where to find them.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

The `event` attribute of `<f:ajax>` can hold *at least* all supported [DOM events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events) of the HTML element which is been generated by the Faces component in question. An easy way to find them all out is to check all `on*` attribues of the Faces input component of interest in the [Faces tag library documentation](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/4.0/vdldoc/) and then remove the "on" prefix. For example, [the `<h:inputText>` component](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/4.0/vdldoc/h/inputtext) which renders `<input type="text">` lists the following `on*` attributes (of which I've already removed the "on" prefix so that it ultimately becomes the DOM event type name):

- `blur`
- `change`
- `click`
- `dblclick`
- `focus`
- `keydown`
- `keypress`
- `keyup`
- `mousedown`
- `mousemove`
- `mouseout`
- `mouseover`
- `mouseup`
- `select`

Additionally, Faces has two more special event names for [`EditableValueHolder`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/10/apidocs/jakarta/faces/component/editablevalueholder) and [`ActionSource`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/10/apidocs/jakarta/faces/component/actionsource) components, the *real* HTML DOM event being rendered depends on the component type:

- `valueChange` (will render as `change` on text/select inputs and as `click` on radio/checkbox inputs)
- `action` (will render as `click` on command links/buttons)

The above two are the *default* events for the components in question.

Some Faces component libraries have additional customized event names which are generally more specialized kinds of `valueChange` or `action` events, such as PrimeFaces `<p:ajax>` which supports among others `tabChange`, `itemSelect`, `itemUnselect`, `dateSelect`, `page`, `sort`, `filter`, `close`, etc depending on the parent `<p:xxx>` component. You can find them all in the "Ajax Behavior Events" subsection of each component's chapter in [PrimeFaces User's Guide](https://www.primefaces.org/documentation/).

Comment: This is a great information, that's what i was looking for. But now i have a little doubt. Will those events in the DOM events link, will make trouble in some browsers? I am interested the most in the events related to drag and drop and focus in and out.

Comment: The standard JSF components indeed don't specify any HTML5 drag'n'drop attributes (the PrimeFaces ones for example may do). You can however find an overview of them all here: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/webappapis.html#event-handlers-on-elements-document-objects-and-window-objects In theory, they will be hooked as such, but you have to make sure that the HTML element which is generated by JSF really supports it. As to the focus in and out, for that you've `focus` and `blur` respectively.

Comment: I understand. So better i make my JSF pages to be html5 so i can have those more advanced features. Thanks for the great answer.

Comment: it is not completely clear to me whether you do clarify that the list you provided is comprehensive for all the components that are ajax-able but each component will support only a subset of what is there.  e.g. `h:form` supports only `click, dblclick, keydown, keypress, keyup, mousedown, mousemove, mouseout, mouseover, mouseup`.  it does not support `focus`, which you have listed.  if you try to use it, you get a `TagException` saying:  `<f:ajax> 'focus' is not a supported event for HtmlForm`

Answer (score 2):

I just input some value that I knew was invalid and here is the output:

> 'whatToInput' is not a supported event for HtmlPanelGrid.
>   Please specify one of these supported event names: click, dblclick,
>   keydown, keypress, keyup, mousedown, mousemove, mouseout, mouseover,
>   mouseup.

So values you can pass to **event** are

- click
- dblclick
- keydown
- mousedown
- mousemove
- mouseover
- mouseup