# How to use <f:ajax> to set updated value in managed bean when value of <h:inputText> is changed

Tags: jsf

I have a JSF page with `<h:inputText>`. I want to set the value bound to the `<h:inputText>` when the value is changed.

Bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScope
public class MyBean {

    private String in;
    //getter and setter

}
```

View:

```
<h:inputText value="#{myBean.in}" />
```

How can I use `<f:ajax>` for this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just nest the `<f:ajax>` tag within the `<h:inputText>` tag.

```
<h:inputText value="#{myBean.in}">
    <f:ajax />
</h:inputText>
```

It'll submit the value when the HTML DOM `change` event has occurred (i.e. when the field was edited and then blurred).

The `event` attribute already defaults to `valueChange`, so it's omitted. Its `execute` attribute already defaults to `@this`, so it's omitted. In case you'd like to update other component on complete, set `render` attribute. E.g.

```
<h:inputText value="#{myBean.in}">
    <f:ajax render="msg" />
</h:inputText>
<h:message id="msg" />
```

If you want to invoke a listener when it has been successfully set, set the `listener` attribute:

```
<h:inputText value="#{myBean.in}">
    <f:ajax listener="#{myBean.changeIn}" />
</h:inputText>
```

```
public void changeIn() {
    System.out.println("in has been changed to " + in);
}
```

#### See also:

- [When to use valueChangeListener or f:ajax listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879138/when-to-use-valuechangelistener-or-fajax-listener)
- [What values can I pass to the event attribute of the f:ajax tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886453/what-values-can-i-pass-to-the-event-attribute-of-the-fajax-tag)

Comment: i am sry for another question

may i add a listener or an actionListener on this <f:ajax/> to excute a method??

Comment: can i add to <f:ajax /> a listener and if yes how is the method structure that will be excuted by this listener