# h:inputText not rerendered when changes h:selectOneMenu value ,doesnt work as expected

Tags: jsf-2, rendering, show-hide

I have a  h:selectOneMenu, and when its value changes to specific value (say "2"), it supposes to show hidden fields then(which hasn't been rendered). Noting that they are linked to the same value of a property in the managed bean.

```
<h:outputText value="Function:"></h:outputText>
<h:selectOneMenu id="funDrp" converter="FunctionConv" value="#{cardBean.card.functionId}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{commonData.functions}" var="c" itemLabel="#{c.description}" itemValue="#{c.functionId}" />
    <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form" event="valueChange" />
</h:selectOneMenu>

<h:outputText value=" Profile Id:" rendered="#{(cardBean.card.functionId.functionId==2)}"></h:outputText>
<h:inputText id="card_refillProfileId"rendered="#{(cardBean.card.functionId.functionId==2)}" label="Refill Profile Id" required="true" value="#{cardBean.card.refillProfileId}"></h:inputText>

<h:outputText value="Origin Type:" rendered="#{(cardBean.card.functionId.functionId==2)}"></h:outputText>
<h:inputText id="card_originType" rendered="#{(cardBean.card.functionId.functionId==2)}" label="Origin Node Type" required="true" value="#{cardBean.card.originType}"></h:inputText>
```

They works fine if the "card" object is assigned to an existing entity, but if it is a new one - it doesnt work as expected.

Comment: Please elaborate "doesnt work as expected" in developer's terms. What exactly happens (not)?

Comment: What is the scope of your backing bean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the value attached to the select one menu was null "card.functionId" .so initializing it just before checking it.as i have tried to initialize it before constructing the bean but it didnt help.

so to do that , initialization was done by attaching a "ValueChangeListener" for the selectOneMenu

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="funDrp" converter="FunctionConv" valueChangeListener="#     {cardBean.changeCardFunc}"
                                            value="#{cardBean.card.functionId}">
                                            <f:selectItems value="#{commonData.functions}" var="c"
                                            itemLabel="#{c.description}" itemValue="#{c.functionId}" />
                                            <f:ajax render="@form" execute="funDrp" event="change" />
                                          </h:selectOneMenu>
```

and in the Managed Bean:

```
public void changeCardFunc(ValueChangeEvent e) {
//  object newFunc= e.

    if(card!=null){
    card.setFunctionId((Function)e.getNewValue());
    }else {
        card= new Card();
        card.setFunctionId((Function)e.getNewValue());
        System.err.println(e.getNewValue());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a fully anticipated behaviour. Using `<f:ajax>` you can rerender HTML elements that are present in your DOM, but by specifying `rendered="false"` in your JSF components they won't appear in your DOM. And, as ajax needs to *find* the element by its id, and replace it afterwards, this job apparently can't be done.

Your job, however, can be handled by embracing your components (all of which use the `rendered` attribute) in a container, for example in `<h:panelGroup id="to-be-rerendered">`, which is always rendered, but its children - not. Thus, ajax will be able to rerender the panel which will include all of your components with `rendered="true"` if the condition is met, and they will appear in your view.

As a side note, your ajax behaviour might be very expensive if your view/form grows. So, if all you want is to rerender *some* components, specify it in your `<f:ajax>` tag: `<f:ajax render="to-be-rerendered" />` (a list of space-separated ids of components to be rendered).

Comment: OP is using `render="@form"`, so I don't see a problem.

Comment: @BalusC I didn't mean it is a problem, but I wanted to point Marwa's attention towards escaping unnesessary renders because it unnecessarily increases the ajax response size.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
<f:ajax render="card_refillProfileId card_originType" execute="@form" event="valueChange" />
```

Comment: I cant render something that doesnt exist http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#AjaxRenderingOfContentWhichIsByItselfConditionallyRendered

Answer (score -1):

Your

```
<f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form" event="valueChange" />
```

Should be (event can be omitted)

```
<f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form" event="change" />
```

It seems there is mismatch between selectOneMenu.value, your converter and the rendered EL.
There is twice `functionId.functionId`. And `selectOneMenu.value` is bind to `cardBean.card.functionId`. I may be wrong if `functionId` is a function.

Comment: They works fine if the "card" object is assigned to an existing entity it works fine ,but if it a new one it doesnt

Comment: What do you mean by `if the "card" object is assigned to an existing entity`? Do you mean if `cardBean.card` is initialized ?

Comment: well I have initialized it everywhere, when i declare it and in @PostConstructor    but that didnt solve it

Comment: `valueChange` event is valid. Even more, it's the default event of `<h:selectOneMenu>`. It can even be omitted altogther. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886453/what-values-can-i-pass-to-the-event-attribute-of-the-fajax-tag/7889098#7889098

Comment: @MarwaDosoky I do not have enough information on the code context to help you.

Comment: The problem was in the initialization , i have solved with something else i am gonna write it down