# JSF Ajax reset previously rendered input component values?

Tags: ajax, jsf

I have a small (but vital) problem with JSF and ajax.  The form is here:

```
 <h:form>
        <h:panelGrid id="pg1" columns="2">

            <h:outputText value="Type: "/>

            <h:selectOneMenu id="selectOne" value="#{personBean.type}">
                <f:selectItems value="#{listBean.personTypes}"/>
                <f:ajax event="valueChange" render="pg2"/>
            </h:selectOneMenu> 

        </h:panelGrid>

        <h:panelGrid id="pg2" columns="2">

            <h:outputText value="Really bad?" rendered="#{personBean.type=='BAD'}"/>

            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="checkbox" value="#{personBean.reallyBad}" rendered="#{personBean.type=='BAD'}">
                <f:ajax event="click"/>
            </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>

        </h:panelGrid>

        <h:commandButton value="Ajax Submit" action="#{personBean.printValues}">
            <f:ajax execute="@form"/>
        </h:commandButton>
    </h:form>
```

The PersonBean is a simple bean with an enum PersonType that has two values: NICE, BAD and a Boolean called reallyBad. The ListBean returns the enum values in a list to populate the selectOneMenu.

Basically when I select BAD the panel for the boolean checkbox is rendered where I can tick it to say a person is reallyBad.  I can then submit the form if I wish.  The problem is when I tick the checkbox and then select NICE again, the checkbox is still ticked even though it is not rendered.  So when I submit my form the person can be NICE and reallyBad, which doesn't make sense.

Rather than having to select BAD again to uncheck the box, is their a way that I can reset the checkbox and its input value to false when NICE is selected?  I'm a bit of a noob to ajax with JSF!  Thanks.

ps. I am printing the values of the two inputs on submit with the commandButtons action to verify the results...

Comment: Can you test is problem present when you remove `f:ajax` from `h:selectBooleanCheckbox`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manually clear the checkbox when you change the menu.

```
<f:ajax listener="#{personBean.setReallyBad(false)}" render="pg2" />
```

By the way, the both `<f:ajax event>` values as you've in your code are the default values already. Just omit them.

Comment: Thanks that worked!  So on the checkbox I can just use <f:ajax/> and it will still work without the event value?  Also, can I get your opinion on this... is it bad practice to have model type logic i.e. rendered="#{personBean.type=='BAD'}" in your view?  I have been told elsewhere it is, mainly for debugging reasons.

Comment: In `UIInput` components, the `event` attribute defaults to `valueChange` already which in turn would generate `click` in case of checkboxes. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886453/what-values-can-i-pass-to-the-event-attribute-of-the-fajax-tag/7889098#7889098