# Rendering p:menu after selecting selectoneradion

Tags: jsf, primefaces

After selecting a radio option in my `.xhtml` page, it will invoke my backing bean method to dynamically construct a menu item with values from DB, and render it `.xhtml` page.

```
<p:selectOneRadio id="userRadio" value="#{applicationBean.selectedUser}" >
    <f:selectItems value="#{applicationBean.usernames1}" />
    <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{applicationBean.displayCommands}" update="commandmenu" />
</p:selectOneRadio>

<p:menu model="#{applicationBean.model}" id="commandmenu" rendered="#{applicationBean.menudisplay}"/>
```

### backing bean method

```
public void displayCommands(AjaxBehaviorEvent event)
{
 System.out.println("The selected user is... "+selectedUser);

 Map<String, String> commands =userCommand.get(selectedUser);

 if(commands!=null)
 {
      System.out.println("the number of commands are.."+commands.size());
      for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : commands.entrySet())
      {
         System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " + entry.getValue());
      }

 }
 this.menudisplay = true;
 FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse();     
}
```

but the p:menu is not rendered. intially

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems with this approach:

1. The `change` event is the wrong event to listen on change of radio buttons and checkboxes. You need `click` instead. Otherwise the 1st click would not trigger the action in a certain browser developed by a team located in Redmond. Even better, just omit the `event` attribute altogether. It defaults to the right one already.
2. You cannot let JS/Ajax update content of something which is initially not rendered by JSF and thus completely absent in the HTML DOM tree. You need to wrap the conditionally rendered JSF component inside another JSF component which is always rendered and thus always present in the HTML DOM tree and thus always available to JS/Ajax by usual `document.getElementById()` ways and so on.

In a nutshell, this is the solution (`event` attribute is removed; `<p:menu>` is placed in a panel group):

```
<p:selectOneRadio id="userRadio" value="#{applicationBean.selectedUser}" >
    <f:selectItems value="#{applicationBean.usernames1}" />
    <p:ajax listener="#{applicationBean.displayCommands}" update="commandmenu" />
</p:selectOneRadio>

<h:panelGroup id="commandmenu">
    <p:menu model="#{applicationBean.model}" rendered="#{applicationBean.menudisplay}"/>
</h:panelGroup>
```

#### See also:

- [What values can I pass to the event attribute of the f:ajax tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886453/what-values-can-i-pass-to-the-event-attribute-of-the-fajax-tag/7889098#7889098)
- [Why do I need to nest a component with rendered="#{some}" in another component when I want to ajax-update it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010734/why-do-i-need-to-nest-a-component-with-rendered-some-in-another-component-w/9010771#9010771)