# List of possible values of event attribute of tag a4j:ajax in RichFaces

Tags: ajax, events, jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I flipped through two RichFaces reference guides and did not find this information. Where else can I search for it?

Comment: It is the same as [`<f:ajax>`](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/core/f_ajax.html).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17680418/exhaustive-list-of-available-events-for-a4jajax

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[List of possible attributes of f:ajax tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886453/what-values-can-i-pass-to-the-event-attribute-of-the-fajax-tag). If one belives Luiggi Mendoza, this list is the same as in a4j:ajax.