# Exhaustive list of available events for a4j:ajax?

Tags: java, ajax, events, jsf, richfaces

Where can I get the exhaustive list of available events for `<a4j:ajax event="..." />`?

[RichFaces's doc](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_X/vdldoc/a4j/ajax.html) says *"name of JavaScript event property (click, change, etc.)"*, but I'm precisely looking for this *"etc."* ;)

Side note: I'm note sure it refers exactly to the [JavaScript events names](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp) since AFAIK, you have to use `selectitem` rather than `select`...

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886453/what-values-can-i-pass-to-the-event-attribute-of-the-fajax-tag/ The `<a4j:ajax>` basically extends `<f:ajax>`. So no new surprises.

Comment: @BalusC The `selectitem` value is especially the kind of *surprises* I would like to know about :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To recite [RichFaces component reference](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html/chap-Component_Reference-Actions.html#sect-Component_Reference-Actions-a4jajax) on the subject (emphasis mine):

> The `<a4j:ajax>` behavior allows Ajax capability to be added to a non-Ajax component. The non-Ajax component **must implement the ClientBehaviorHolder interface for all the event attributes that support behavior rendering**.

To proceed one step further one should look into [`ClientBehaviorHolder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/behavior/ClientBehaviorHolder.html) interface, especially the `ClientBehaviorHolder#getEventNames()` method that

> Returns a non-null, unmodifiable Collection **containing the names of the logical events supported by the component** implementing this interface

This way it would not be too tough to find out the list of events the component can fire.

Basically, as you suspected, all basic JavaScript events are supported and a set of custom ones that are (typically) mentioned in component's documentation (those with `on` prefix), but with prefix omitted (like `onlistshow` would turn into `event="listshow"`).

Also, it is worth mentioning that there are two additional 'standard' event types in JSF that will render the necessary/right HTML DOM event, depending on the component in question. Those are `action` for components that implement `ActionSource` interface and `valueChange` for components that implement `EditableValueHolder`.

Answer (score 0):

The list of available events depends on what component you're working with. All the Mouse, Keyboard and Form events should be supported (not sure about the onerror and such) and if you're working with, say, `<rich:select>` you get access to custom events like `listclick`, `listdblclick`, `selectitem` etc. which are described in the [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/4.3.X/4.3.0.CR1/vdldoc/rich/select.html).