# Using JSF 2.x ,how to update other UI components from a change in current component

Tags: jsf, selectonemenu

I have a selectOneMenu and below it I have a selectManyListbox . Based on what user has selected in selectOneMenu , I want to refresh selectManyListbox . Like for example say selectOneMenu has list of Students and selectManyListbox  has list of Courses. So for example in this scenario, say if I select Student1 then automatically selectManyListbox should show Course1, Course9 as selected. If I change selectOneMenu to student2 then accordingly selectManyListbox  should show his courses as selected ones. What would be the general strategy of doing this?.

Comment: Thanks!. This one matches my use case exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You could fire a change in selectOneMenu and fill the selectManyListBox's value.

```
<f:ajax event="change"/>
```

or 
if you are using primefaces, you could use  `<p:ajax event="change"/>`

See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806364/fajax-by-onchange-event)