# <f:ajax> doesn't work on PrimeFaces component

Tags: ajax, jsf, events, primefaces

I trying to use the `onChange` event of `selectOneMenu`, but it doesn't work and the component is not displayed when I add `onChange` attribue.

Can someone tell me how can I handle the `onChange` event of  `<p:selectOneMenu>`?

Here is my view:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="service" filterMatchMode="startsWith">  
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selectionner un Service : "  />  
    <f:selectItems value="#{newOpProgramme.listeSevice}" var="service" itemValue="#{service.serviceId}" itemLabel="#{service.serviceNom}"/>
    <f:ajax event="change" execute="@this" listener="#{newOpProgramme.serviceChange()}" render="nomCdp"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

And here is the `<f:ajax listener>` method in a request scoped bean:

```
public void serviceChange() {
    System.out.println("change");
}
```

When I change the menu, however, nothing is been printed.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: 1. Post your code; 2. You have to use the attribute `onchange`. `selectOneMenu` does not have the attribute `onChange`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

First of all, `onChange` is the wrong event name. It's `change`. Secondly, if you intend to call the HTML attribute name, `onChange` is also the wrong attribute name. It's `onchange`.

Coming back to your concrete problem; the standard JSF `<f:ajax>` is not compatible with PrimeFaces components. You should be using PrimeFaces own [`<p:ajax>`](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/listener.xhtml) instead.

```
<p:selectOneMenu ...>
    ...
    <p:ajax listener="#{newOpProgramme.serviceChange()}" update="nomCdp" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Note that I omitted the `event` and the `process` attributes. They both have already the right default value of `valueChange` and `@this` respectively.

#### See also:

- [What values can I pass to the event attribute of the f:ajax tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886453/what-values-can-i-pass-to-the-event-attribute-of-the-fajax-tag)
- [Understanding PrimeFaces process/update and JSF f:ajax execute/render attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-process-and-update-attributes-of-primefaces/)

Answer (score 1):

When I want to update something after change in selectOneMenu, I use `<f:ajax>` tag inside selectOneMenu like this:

```
  <h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.selected}" >
... select items here
     <f:ajax event="change" execute="@this" render="search" />
  </h:selectOneMenu>
```

Where search is the `Id` of the object you want to update.

Other solution is that you should try `onchange` not `onChange`.

Comment: thank for your answer, but how can I call a function from my managedBean ?

Comment: You can use listener attribute of f:ajax.

`<f:ajax event="change" execute="@this" render="search" listener="#{bean.method()}"/>`

Comment: So post your code. I don't have any idea how to solve that, without details.

Comment: Yeah, if you are using primefaces selectOneMenu use BalusC solution with p:ajax except f:ajax.

Answer (score -1):

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{someBean.myAttr.id}" valueChangeListener="#someBean.mySelectioMethodListener}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{someBean.listAttrs}" var="item"
        itemLabel="#{item.name}" itemValue="#{item.id}" />
    <p:ajax process="@this" update="someElementId" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

You must put an Id for `<f:selectItems />` and set your selection on backing bean side by posted ajax itemValue (id).

Server side method bean without a converter:

```
public void mySelectionMethodListener(ValueChangeEvent event) {
ApplicationContext context = FacesContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());        
    SomeBeanDao someBeanDao = (SomeBeanDao) context.getBean(SomeBeanDao.class);
    myAttr = someBeanDao.byId((Long) event.getNewValue());
    System.out.println("value changed...");
}
```