# p:selectOneMenu ajax change event not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have the following component on the xhtml:

```
            <p:outputLabel for="concept" value="Concept" />
        <p:selectOneMenu id="concept" value="#{dIGRCController.digrc.qconce}"
            requiredMessage="Debe de seleccionar un concepto."
            required="#{request.getParameter('validate')}">

            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Concept" itemValue="" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{cCRX1Controller.ccrx1.concepts.entrySet()}"
                var="concepts" itemValue="#{concepts.key}"
                itemLabel="#{concepts.value}" />

            <p:ajax event="change" execute="@this" listener="#{dIGRCController.testing()}" />

        </p:selectOneMenu>
```

The values are coming correctly from the cCRX1Controller class. However, when I select an option, I am trying to display the value. the #{dIGRCController.testing()} looks like this:

```
public void testing()
{
    System.out.println("sdfsd");
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18329433/pselectonemenu-onchange-event-doesnt-work) question but could't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: You want to make sure it's in a form.  You also want to make sure that the dIGRCController is the right name of your  Class.

Comment: `execute` is wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this

```
<p:ajax process="@this" listener="#{dIGRCController.testing()}" />
```

I think the default of `ajax` event of `Primefaces` select one menu is `valueChange` event. So, try with using also

```
<p:ajax event="valueChange" process="@this" listener="#{dIGRCController.testing()}" />
```

Comment: and what if I have public void testing(AjaxBehaviorEvent event)? :) Different number of formal and actual parameter error