# Output string inputText with ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf

I try to get experiment with ajax. I want that string from inputText typing to outpuLabel.

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText id="str" value="#{f.str}">
        <f:ajax render="num"/>
    </h:inputText>
    <h:outputLabel id="num" value="#{f.str}">
    </h:outputLabel>
</h:form>
```

But the value of `num` update only when i'm typed and clicked the mouse, not during typing to `str`. How do that the `num` will be updating during the typing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`<f:ajax event>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/ajax.html) defaults in case of [`UIInput`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html) components to `valueChange` which renders in case of [`<h:inputText>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/inputText.html) the ajax call in the `onchange` attribute of the generated `<input type="text">` element (you can see it yourself by opening the JSF page in webbrowser and do rightclick and *View Source*).

So, the ajax request is only fired when the HTML DOM `change` event is fired. That is, when you change the value of the input element and then the input element loses focus (blurs).

As per your functional requirement, you actually want the ajax request to be fired when the HTML DOM `keyup` event is fired. In that case, you'd need to explicitly specify that.

```
<f:ajax event="keyup" ... />
```

#### See also:

- [What values can I pass to the event attribute of the f:ajax tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886453/what-values-can-i-pass-to-the-event-attribute-of-the-fajax-tag/7889098#7889098)

Comment: Thanks for exhaustive answer!