# Trigger <cc:clientBehavior> event from <p:ajax> nested in composite

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, composite-component

Is there any way to trigger an event in my composite component with clientBehavior and jQuery?

If not possible, what is the proper way to create custom events in composites?

Example:

ajaxTest.xhtml:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:cc="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <cc:interface>
        <cc:clientBehavior name="myEvent" targets="myLabel" event="myEvent"/>
    </cc:interface>

    <cc:implementation>
        <div id="#{cc.clientId}">
            <p:outputLabel id="myLabel" value="Test label" />
            <p:commandLink value="trigger event"
                           onstart="$(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('#{cc.clientId}:myLabel')).trigger('myEvent');"/>            
        </div>
    </cc:implementation>
</html>
```

testPage.xhtml:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
        xmlns:demo="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite/component">

<h:body>
        <h:form id="form-1">
            <demo:ajaxTest>
                <p:ajax event="myEvent" oncomplete="alert('Ajax called');" />
            </demo:ajaxTest>
        </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<cc:clientBehavior event>` must declare a valid event name as supported by the target component in question. In this context, it must thus be exactly the same event name as you would use when nesting `<p:ajax>` directly inside `<p:commandLink>`. You perhaps want `action` or `click`.

```
<cc:clientBehavior ... event="action" />
```

#### See also:

- [What values can I pass to the event attribute of the f:ajax tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886453/what-values-can-i-pass-to-the-event-attribute-of-the-fajax-tag/)

Comment: You're right, in the current context this is not a jQuery problem, so I may oversimplified it.
I am trying to integrate a jQuery addon (ShapeShift 2) to my composite, and I don't have any idea, how can I trigger ajax events from jQuery .on() callbacks. Is this problem worth another question?

Comment: You could use `<p:remoteCommand>`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588327/how-to-invoke-a-jsf-managed-bean-on-a-html-dom-event-using-native-javascript/