# Focus event for JSF h:form component

Tags: ajax, jsf

I would like to trigger an AJAX call when the user sets focus within an `h:form`, any field in the form.  I explicitly do not want the call to be triggered when (s)he moves the cursor between different form fields.  I currently do it using the `click` event in an `f:ajax` tag:

```
<h:form>                        
    <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{myController.formFocusResponse}"/>
```

However, that triggers each time the user clicks on the form.  If there are 5 form fields, the ajax call is triggered each time the user moves onto the next field.

The available events for the form are:

```
click
dblclick
keydown
keypress
keyup
mousedown
mousemove
mouseout
mouseover
mouseup
```

**Q1:**  Why is something like a `focus` or `select` event supported for h:form which, unlike the `click`, only gets triggered when the user first enters the form component?

**Q2:**  Is there a way to hack or simulate a call trigger using other events or any other tool from the JSF kit?

Comment: If you convert all the JSF components into its HTML code, then this question can suit for `html` and `javascript` tags, where you could get more help. JSF doesn't have an important role in this.

Comment: your suggestion has merit, however, my API is JSF and not HTML/JS, despite being the foundational platform for JSF.  because I plan to implement this in JSF and not straight JS (IOW, I like having HSF-generated JS), i would prefer to retain the scope of JSF

Comment: I think you misunderstood my comment. I'm not saying stop using JSF by any mean, but giving you a recommendation about how to solve your problem. Your problem boils down to a javascript event on `<form>` HTML component, and for that point, JSF is just a mere HTML generator. So, you would have more people to help you if you focus your question as HTML + Javascript. The real implementation can be done using JSF and/or another framework like PrimeFaces.

Comment: Also, note that `event` in `<f:ajax>` can support any defined event on the HTML component.

Comment: actually, your last statement is not true.  the availability of ajax events in JSF is contingent on the component into which the ajax tag is nested.  the list i provided above is for h:form.  some of HTML supported events are `select` and `focus` but they are not supported for `h:form`

Comment: refer this this answer for a full list of supported events.  now, some may not be available for some components:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886453/what-values-can-i-pass-to-the-event-attribute-of-the-fajax-tag

Comment: I was about to tell you to check that Q/A where BalusC cearly status that `focus` is supported. Then again, probably you cannot replicate this. I've just made a test for `<form onfocus="alert('foo')">` and **doesn't work**, which means your problem is not about JSF but about HTML + JavaScript. Then again, JSF is just a mere HTML generator for your problem.