# Is this the sequence of how f:ajax executes and affects the response render cycle

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2.2

I'm new to JSF and I'm trying to understand more by examples in books and online. That's actually how I easily learn things instead of just reading. So, examples works best for me.

I am trying to understand the exact sequence of what's happening in this code example I saw on one of the video tutorials. To be specific, the `f:ajax` execution and the `listener` attribute

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h:inputFile value="#{uploadController.image}">
      <f:passThroughAttribute name="accept" value="image/png"/>
      <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{uploadController.doUpload()}" execute="@form" render="@form"/>
      </h:inputFile>
</h:form>
```

I'm  trying to understand the step by step order of execution. So the way I understand this is

**1.** `f:ajax event` - listens to any **changes** that may occur on the `h:inputFile component` whose value is binded to a Java `ManagedBean` class and initially has a `null` value and gets set once the user/client selects and image file. (so from initial value of null, null value is replaced with the file chosen by the client.

**2.** `execute="@form"` - sends or *posts* all the components(such as `h:inputFile`, `h:inputText` etc) values contained in the `h:form`

**3.** Everytime the `h:inputFile` value is **changed**(*either from null or another file is selected*), the `#{uploadController.doUpload()}` EL expression is triggered which results to calling the `doUpload()` method which **automatically** uploads the file.

**4.** Lastly, `render="@form"` updates the look and values of forms (not really sure about what exactly happens in `render="@form"`

Am I correct with my understanding of what exactly this `f:ajax` tag and its attributes does?

I'm asking this because I know that incorporating `f:ajax` with jsf will improve the performance of a web application as it only **updates** or **renders** **partials** or **parts** of the page and gives the advantage of not having to reload the entire page.

Comment: Your question is quite broad. The abovelinked duplicate answers the execute/action/render parts and this duplicate answers the event part http://stackoverflow.com/q/7886453

Comment: By the way, I recommend to take a step back and learn basic HTML/JavaScript too. See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/1958808 Namely, the way you formulated the question gives a strong impression that you don't seem to realize that JSF is "just" a HTML/JS code generator.