# JSF 2 button ajax action execution with image

Tags: jsf-2

The action in the button does not execute when image attribute is there , any Ideas on how to solve it:

```
<h:commandButton id="delete" style="vertical-align: bottom"                         
   action="#{uploadComponentBean.delete(docList.id)}"
   image="images/delete.gif">
   <f:ajax event="click" render="table1" />
</h:commandButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the event of `f:ajax` to action like this:

```
   <f:ajax event="action" render="table1" />
```

it works for me. 
for more detail check [ajax events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886453/what-values-can-i-pass-to-the-event-attribute-of-the-fajax-tag)